# Complete email input as soon as @ is typed

Tags: jquery

In an input type email, I try to add the domain name as soon as the @ character has been typed.
For example, if a user has entered john.doe@, I try to add yourdomain.com.
I have written the following code but when it's run, it displays john.doe@yourdomain.com@.

How can I get rid of the last @ character ?

```js
$(document).on('keypress', 'input#email', function(e) {
  console.log('keypress champ mail');
  if (e.which !== 64) {
    console.log("Charcter was typed. It was: " + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    console.log(this.value);
  } else {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    //process the single character or
    var textValue = this.value;
    var fulltext = textValue + c + "yourdomain.com";
    console.log(fulltext);
    this.value = "";
    this.value = fulltext;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email">
```

Comment: Once the input has been correctly filled, how can I submit the form it belongs to ? I tried $('form#form_sign').submit(function(){console.log('submission);}); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you require you need to call `preventDefault()` on the `keypress` event when the `@` key is pressed. Also note that you can tidy up the logic. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', 'input#email', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 64) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    this.value = this.value + c + "yourdomain.com";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="email" />
```

It could also be argued that the `var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);` line is redundant, as it will *always* be `'@'`, but I'll leave that for you to decide.